# MobX : How to observe only selected part of the entire store?

Tags: mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree, mobx-react-lite

The variable Models will store an array of model objects.
`SelectedIndex` will get changed by the UI through the action `setSelectedIndex`.

The Action `addToResult` should add the incoming data to the selected model and It should get reflected in the `UI` as well.

Here The problem is that, after executing the action `addToResult`, `UI` does not get updated.

```
 export default class Store {
  
  selectedIndex: number = -1

  @observable.deep activeModel: Model = undefined

      @action addToResult = (results: string[]) => {
    this.model[this.selectedIndex].results.push(results[0])
  }

  @action setSelectedIndex = (index: number) => {
    this.selectedIndex = index
    this.activeModel = {
      ...this.models[this.selectedIndex]
    }
  }

  models: Model[] = []

  constructor () {
    makeObservable(this)
  }

}
```